# Play 2 Scala feed a Websocket output Iteratee with several enumerators (PatchPannel?)

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket, loops

I would like to feed a WebSocket output Iteratee with several enumerators progressively (for example I want to add a specific enumerator to the output Iteratee when I receive a specific event through the Websocket input iteratee).

If I am right this is impossible if I just return `(in,out)` at the end of the Websocket function argument as out is already an immutable enumerator:

```scala
WebSocket.using[JsValue] { request =>
    val in: Iteratee[JsValue,Unit] = ...
    val out: Enumerator[JsValue] = ...

    (in, out)
}
```

I think that Concurrent.PatchPannel is what I am looking for, but I can't manage to understand how to use it. Does anyone have an example of using Concurrent.PatchPannel? (if this is indeed what I am looking for).

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have finally found the solution myself.

Edit: See the "Mixable sub-streams" section in my blog post: http://atamborrino.github.io/play/2013/12/25/play-framework-websocket.html